# Странная ошибка при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android

Знакомлюсь с Android Studio и сразу столкнулся с некоторыми ошибками при запуске приложения. Создаю новый проект - все запускается, добавляю хотя бы одну кнопку, запускаю и ловлю ряд следующих ошибок. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете мне решить данную проблему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой файл Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.youcanbetter.appformepoint"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: День добрый. Приведите ошибку текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы забыли закрывающую фигурную скобку в последнем методе MainActivity, о чем вам IDE услужливо сообщает подчеркиванием

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас 2 метода onCreate, конфликтующих между собой. В добавок у последнего нет закрывающей фигурной скобки

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, разобрался